# How i can change number of likes by pressing the svg icon for only that specific element?

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg

```js
/*I selected svg and number.I want to change number of like by clicking first heart from 24 to 25 and not to affect to second one.Same for second one*/

const svg = document.querySelectorAll('.icon');
const number = document.querySelectorAll('#number')

svg.forEach(el => {
    el.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
        const id = e.currentTarget;
        if (id) {
            this.classList.toggle('is-selected')


        }
        if (id.classList.contains('is-selected')) {
            number.forEach(el => {
                el.innerHTML++
            })
        } else {
            number.forEach(el => {
                el.innerHTML--
            })
        }


    })
})
```

```css
/*Here i make hover on svg icon and class that changes the color of hearth when is clicked*/

.icon.is-outlined {
  stroke: #5d5d5d;
  stroke-width: 2px;
  fill: transparent;
  height: 18px;
  width: 18px;
}

.icon.is-hoverable:hover {
  fill: #d75a4a;
  stroke: #d75a4a;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.icon.is-selected {
  fill: #d75a4a;
  stroke: #d75a4a;
}
```

```html
<p><span class="heart"><svg class="icon is-x2 is-outlined is-hoverable is-transit " viewBox="0 0 32 32">
                    <use xlink:href="#heart-icon"></use>
                  </svg></span> <span id="number">24</span> people love this</p>

<p><span class="heart"><svg class="icon is-x2 is-outlined is-hoverable is-transit" viewBox="0 0 32 32">
                    <use xlink:href="#heart-icon"></use>
                  </svg></span> <span id="number">2</span> people love this</p>

<svg height="0" width="0" style="position:absolute;margin-left: -100%;">
    <path id="heart-icon" d="M16,28.261c0,0-14-7.926-14-17.046c0-9.356,13.159-10.399,14-0.454c1.011-9.938,14-8.903,14,0.454
        C30,20.335,16,28.261,16,28.261z" />
  </svg>
```

Answer (score 1):

You are using 'number' id for both of them. You should use an ID for only one. ID is unique.
Use different IDs for each span.

Comment: I change ID but still when i click on second span svg icon  change the first number of likes by one.

Answer (score 0):

In a modern Browser (anything above IE) you can create your own HTML tag and contain all functionality within, and the whole tag is clickable.

```html
    <loving-heart count="21"></loving-heart>
    <loving-heart count="2"></loving-heart>
```

You could do it without shadowDOM, but then your CSS becomes more complex.
Using shadowDOM ensure all CSS is contained within the Custom Element/Web Component

```html
<loving-heart count="21"></loving-heart>
<loving-heart count="2"></loving-heart>

<script>
  customElements.define('loving-heart', class extends HTMLElement {
    static get observedAttributes() {
      return ["count"]; // count can be set from any JavaScript code
    }
    connectedCallback() {
      let style = `<style>
:host{display:flex;cursor:pointer;stroke:#5d5d5d;stroke-width:2px;fill:transparent}
:host([selected]),
:host(:hover){fill:#d75a4a;stroke:#d75a4a}
div{width:1.5em;text-align:right;padding-right:.2em}</style>`;
      this.attachShadow({mode: "open"})
          .innerHTML = style + `<svg height='1em' viewBox='0 0 30 30'>
      <path d="M15 28c0 0-14 -8 -14 -17c0-9 13 -10 14 -1c1-9 14 -8 14 1c0 8-14 17 -14 17z"/></svg>` +
        `<div></div>people love this`;
      this.count = this.count; // force initial update
      this.onclick = () => this.setAttribute("selected", this.count++);
    }
    get count() {
      return ~~this.getAttribute("count"); // cast attribute string to number
    }
    set count(v) {
      this.setAttribute("count", v); // trigger attributeChangedCallback
    }
    attributeChangedCallback(name, oldValue, newValue) {
      if (oldValue) this.shadowRoot.querySelector("div").innerHTML = newValue;
    }
  });
  document.querySelector("loving-heart").count = 42;
</script>
```